# JetBrains' @NotNull works only when project built from IDEA

Tags: java, maven, validation, annotations, notnull

I wrote a simple project to learn how to work with annotation validation.
For that puspose I added maven dependency (also I tried javax.validation, that does not work for me):

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.jetbrains</groupId>
    <artifactId>annotations</artifactId>
    <version>15.0</version>
</dependency>
```

and used it this way:

```
public boolean add(@NotNull T entry){ ...
```

When I build the project from IDEA, everything is fine, but it does not work when compiling the code with maven command.
In decompiled class file I noticed that IDEA compiles my classes in different way. It adds this check:

```
if (entry == null) {
    $$$reportNull$$$0(0);
}
```

And maven does not.

I'm I doing something wrong? Please, tell me how it should be used (no matter jetbrains or javax validation).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why @Nonnull annotation checked at runtime?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40847472/why-nonnull-annotation-checked-at-runtime)

Comment: That is IntelliJ IDEA 2016.3 feature(not very nice though).

Answer (score 1):

Partially guessing here: you see, it is not "IDEA" that puts that extra check into the byte code.

The thing is: annotations can also be used to **generate** code (see [here](https://deors.wordpress.com/2011/10/08/annotation-processors/) for some further reading). And as you can see from that link; the core thing for **code generation** is: that annotation requires a javax.annotation.processing.Processor class. And that will be used by the **compiler** to turn the source code annotation into something reasonable within byte code.

If I get you right, you failed to get those javax parts setup for your maven compile. So probably the one part is missing there; so the solution is to fix your maven setup to provide all required dependencies.

Answer (score 0):

Your `@NotNull` annotation seems to be part of IntelliLang plugin, designed to support coding in IDEA (i.e. helps in contract coding). I doubt it is available outside of IDEA.

> Before you start working with language injections, make sure that the IntelliLang plugin is enabled. The plugin is bundled with IntelliJ IDEA and is activated by default

I don't know much about it, so please say hello to [reference](http://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2016.3/nullable-and-notnull-annotations.html#d1797147e49)

`javax.validation` on the other hand is designed to quite different things. It checks if data object content is valid via [Bean Validation](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/gircz.html) from java EE

Answer (score 0):

A Maven plug-in was created to do the same thing for Maven builds:

https://github.com/osundblad/intellij-annotations-instrumenter-maven-plugin

It only works with JetBrains annotations by default.

Answer (score 0):

As noted by other answers, Intellij implemented a process to add the null checks to your code before it is compiled. There is one unofficial maven plugin (https://github.com/osundblad/intellij-annotations-instrumenter-maven-plugin) and some forks of it, but it is not longer maintained (last change was over a year ago) and I couldn't get it to work.

Thus, I recommend using another annotation instead. In my project, I switched to Lombok instead, which also has some nice additional features. To get it to work, you explicitly need to tell Lombok to throw another exception. See this working example:

#### Prequisites:

You need to add the lombok dependency to your maven pom.xml (find the latest version [here](https://search.maven.org/artifact/org.projectlombok/lombok)):

```xml
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
        <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
        <version>${lombok.version}</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

In your root directory (inside the folder, that contains 'src') create a lombok.config with the following content:

```
lombok.nonNull.exceptionType=IllegalArgumentException
```

#### 1. Use case

Now you can use the `@NonNull` annotation for parameters and the null-checks will be generated automatically. You probably also need to add the maven-surefire-plugin to your pom.xml.

#### 2. Use case

There is a neat possibility to let Lombok figure out itself, when the null check is necessary and when not for constructors. The following code will generate a constructor with to parameters (list1, list2). But it will only throw an IllegalArgmentException/NullPointerException, if the argument 'list1' is `null`, because list2 is not annotated with `@NonNull`.

```java
import lombok.RequiredArgsConstructor;
import java.util.List;

@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class A {

    @NonNull
    private final List<String> list1;

    private final List<String> list2;
    
    ...
}
```