# Can't avoid Intellij throwing IllegalArgumentException with @NotNull

Tags: java, intellij-idea, notnull, non-nullable

Is there anything else I can do when [unchecking "Add runtime assertions for not-null annotated methods and parameters"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40847472/why-nonnull-annotation-checked-at-runtime) doesn't work? It keeps throwing `IllegalArgumentException`. I've also tried disabling the Inspections for `@NotNull/@Nullable problems` and `Constant conditions & exception`s. I've restarted and restarted and invalidated the caches, and switching annotations in `Configure annotations`.

I'm using:

```
IntelliJ IDEA 2017.2.5
Build #IC-172.4343.14, built on September 26, 2017
JRE: 1.8.0_152-release-915-b12 amd64
JVM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM by JetBrains s.r.o
Linux 4.4.0-98-generic
```

on Ubuntu 16.

Any idea?

Comment: Please share the [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Did you figure out? I have same issue with Intellij 2017 + Ubuntu 16.

Answer (score 0):

It's feature/bug of `Java build 1.8.0_15X`

I've solved this issue with downgrading to `Java build 1.8.0_25`.